# Why can't I put map correctly as argument in elixir?

Tags: elixir

I'm playing with `use` functionality in elixir. I can't understand one thing:

```
defmodule Alex do
  use Included,
    names: [:helen, :rebekka],
    states: [
      %{
        :name => :start
      }, [
        name: :finish
      ]
end
```

I placed different constructors (map & keyword) just to show the difference. I have a simple elixir module which returns me a values:

```
defmodule Included do
  demacro __using__(opts) do
    IO.puts Keyword.get(opts, :names) # => [:helen, :rebekka]
    IO.puts Keyword.get(:states) # => [{:%{}, [line: 8], [name: :start]}, [name: :finish]]
  end
end
```

Why do I receive this strange map and how can I get normal maps in my module?

Comment: Two suggestions: 1.) Learn more about Elixir before you play with macros. There are ways to do some of the stuff you want to do without using macros and using something besides macros is a far better approach from the standpoint of being able to maintain code. 2.) If you want to learn macros, there's a great book on the subject: https://pragprog.com/book/cmelixir/metaprogramming-elixir

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I read the whole Programming Elixir by Dave Thomas, hehe ;) Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 2):

What you get is the AST representation of the `opts`, just like any arguments that are passed to macros. If you are using proplists, these happen to take the same form in quoted an unquoted form:

```
iex> [name: :finish]
[name: :finish]

iex> quote do: [name: :finish]
[name: :finish]
```

Maps however don't, because they are not among the basic data types:

```
iex> %{name: :finish}
%{name: :finish}

iex> quote do: %{name: :finish}
{:%{}, [], [name: :finish]}
```

This is the reason why proplists are the preferred way to pass options to a macro. However, you can use an unquoted map within a `quote` as expected:

```
defmodule Included do
  defmacro __using__(opts) do
    quote do
      IO.inspect unquote(opts)
    end
  end
end

defmodule Alex do
  use Included, %{name: :start}
end
```

This will simply print

```
%{name: :start}
```